# How to printfn int*int*int type

Tags: f#

```
> (1, 2, 3);;
val it : int * int * int = (1, 2, 3)

> printfn "%d" (1, 2 ,3);;

  printfn "%d" (1, 2 ,3);;
  --------------^^^^^^^

stdin(2,15): error FS0001: The type '('a * 'b * 'c)' is not compatible with any of the types byte,int16,int32,int64,sbyt
e,uint16,uint32,uint64,nativeint,unativeint, arising from the use of a printf-style format string
```

How can I printfn this type without creating additional function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can print any type with the formatter %A:

```
printfn "%A" (1, 2, 3);;
```

Otherwise you will need to unpack your tuple to print it as there are no formatters specific for tuples.

Comment: Just to add, "%A" will be slow if you try it on some large recursive data structure.. as this uses reflection to navigate the data structure and print the result